# exoplayer.setThrowsWhenUsingWrongThread(false) is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, exoplayer

`exoplayer.setThrowsWhenUsingWrongThread(false)` is **deprecated** in Exoplayer latest version, is there any alternative to it because when I remove it then it gives,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Player is accessed on the wrong thread.
Current thread: 'DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Expected thread: 'main'
```

exoplayer works fine if I use it, but it's **deprecated**.
Thank you for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setThrowsWhenUsingWrongThread()` has become deprecated for the following reason according to the official [documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html#setThrowsWhenUsingWrongThread(boolean)): `"Disabling the enforcement can result in hard-to-detect bugs. Do not use this method except to ease the transition while wrong thread access problems are fixed."` The official [release notes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md) extend on this commentary by mentioning the method will be removed entirely upon the next major release.

There's no alternative outside of complying to the library's strict single-thread paradigm. Please see the Hello World's [note on threading](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html#a-note-on-threading) and the [threading model](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html) section of the official documentation. You can employ `setThrowsWhenUsingWrongThread(false)` in the meantime as it's only deprecated, but you'll need to comply if you would like to utilize upcoming features.

Comment: Yes, I referred to the documentation. I don't think using the deprecated function until the next major release will cause any issue!
Thanks!